# Large object marshalling using JAXB loses characters

Tags: java, jaxb, kml, jak

I'm using the [JavaAPIForKml](http://code.google.com/p/javaapiforkml/) to generate large KML objects and marshal them to a file.

When the output reaches a certain size I end up losing an angle bracket (`<`).  It seems like there's a buffer that's being used and a bug is causing the character to be dropped.

Has anyone seen this or know how to fix it?

Comment: Which JAXB implementation are you using (Metro, MOXy, JaxMe, etc)?

Comment: How can I tell?  I'm running Orion server within Eclipse, I'm fairly certain it's the JAXB implementation that comes with the JRE, because if I select JAXBContext in my code and hit F3 it takes me to rt.jar

Comment: Metro is the default implementation that comes with the JRE. It certainly sounds like a bug based on your description.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Metro. I've tried using the JRE version and the latest from Sun, but to no avail. Has anyone seen this?  It seems that it only happens if one element gets too large.  I can have a million small elements in the file, but if one grows too large (including its descendants) I have the problem. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the KML that was generated was completely valid.  I was using Chrome in view-source mode, it seems that a bug in Chrome was dropping characters.